# In Memory Database Acessible From Multiple Python Scripts?

Tags: python, database

I'm searching for a fast, **in-memory database** that allows one to define, initialize & manipulate a `large matrix` of floats (of approx. size `10,000,000 x 10`).

This **in-memory database** must meet the following requirements:

**(1)** be open source, and easy to setup in a `Linux` environment

**(2)** have an existing, easy to use `python` module that allows one to interact with it

**(3)** be entirely in-memory, and indexable (no queries / sql are needed)

**(4)** allow few different `python` scripts (running at the same time...) to access the same **matrix** and read from it / update it (**note:** updates must be *atomic* -- so the DB should know how to handle concurrency)

---

Here's what I am trying to do:   I have a couple of different `python` scripts *running at the same time*. All of them are running *on the same machine*, yet are independent -- and share nothing with each other.

I am trying to have them all use the `same output matrix` to *update their results* (I want all of their results to be stored in ONE BIG MATRIX).

Hence, I need a solution that will allow them all to **read from** and **update** **the same matrix**.

Ideally, updates will be done using the following line of code:

```
myMatrix[a][b] = 23.44
```

As you can see, *sql* is **not needed** as each `python` script will be directly manipulating the matrix.

---

I am willing to consider *any solution* as long as it meets the above criteria. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** I don't have to use a matrix necessarily; a *key/value DB* can also work.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want a database, then.  Have you looked at numpy much?  You can share the same memory (and map it as a numpy array) between processes, though there are a few caveats, and a gazillion different ways of going about it. Search for "numpy shared memory" or something similar.

Comment: i'm puzzled: independent, not sharing anything yet you want them to be able to *read* the matrix?

Comment: Joe Kington, a `numpy ndarray` is exactly what I need! I did not know that you can share the same `numpy ndarray` among different processes; can you provide more examples?

Comment: fvu, it is my mistake. The different processes DO SHARE the `output matrix` -- they should all be able to read from it / update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rather different approach [based on a message queuing system](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Divide-and-Conquer).  Probably the Ventilator and Sink roles will be folded into one for your purpose, and of course it will only work if the ventilator can decide what data need to be sent off to the workers, unless you supplement it with a shared memory solution.

EDIT: the pattern remains valid, but python has its own queue system on board that may be sufficient.  [This pdf](http://folk.uio.no/sturlamo/python/multiprocessing-tutorial.pdf) could help you getting started.

Comment: fvu, thank you. Yes, `zmq` with Ventilator and Sink is definitely an option. Let me ask you this: can the `ventilator` handle say 10 different `python` scripts, each sending over to it say `3[MB]` every 2[sec] or so?

Comment: Most of the benchmarking I've been doing with zmq was on very small embedded machines and even there performance was pretty impressive.  I think the available bandwidth will ultimately be the most constraining factor.  On the page I sent you you'll find  ready-to run implementations in Python, might be a good idea to modify these to fit your use case and perform some benchmarking.

Answer (score 1):

May be [Redis](http://redis.io/) will fit your needs. It's fast in-memory key/value DB. It has [List](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro) type for storing sequence of elements but it's implemented as linked list not as array. So accessing element by index in 10M list may be not so fast. But you can have 10M keys if your matrix has 10M x 10 elements. Redis also support transactions.

Comment: great, I will take it into account